# Difference between Conv2D and Convolution2D in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, convolution, keras-layer

There is already an answer wrt to Tensorflow.
But the problem is that
In my IDE
Conv2D is a class
while Convolution2D is a variable?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From the [keras source code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/convolutional.py/#L2573), they're the same:
(The source code changes from time to time and the line number in the link above might eventually be wrong)

```
# Aliases

Convolution1D = Conv1D
Convolution2D = Conv2D
Convolution3D = Conv3D
SeparableConvolution2D = SeparableConv2D
Convolution2DTranspose = Conv2DTranspose
Deconvolution2D = Deconv2D = Conv2DTranspose
Deconvolution3D = Deconv3D = Conv3DTranspose
```

Comment: Why am i getting this warning UserWarning: Update your `Conv2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(64, 64, 3..., activation="relu")`
  classifier.add(Conv2D(32,3,3,input_shape=(64,64,3),activation='relu'))

Comment: Because you're passing parameters in a style that was ok in Keras1, but is not the keras 2 way of doing it. It still supports the old way, but it gives you this message. Notice the `kernel_size=(3,3)`. This is how it should be done in keras 2.